# Problems with get() for Tkinter widgets

Tags: get, python-2.7, widget, tkinter

I'm having an issue getting a value out of my entry boxes with Tkinter.  What I'm trying to work with right now is

```
S1 = Entry(attr,
           width = 3).grid(row = 0,
                           column = 1)
L = Label(attr,
          width = 5,
          relief = RIDGE,
          anchor = E,
          text = "STR: ").grid(row = 0,
                               column = 0)
```

with a button at the end to attempt to get multiple values out (several .get()s instead of just the one here)

```
def Process():
   SEN = S1.get()

Button(attr,
       text = 'Continue',
       command=Process).grid(row = 8, column = 0)
```

I have the labels and Entrys set up as their own functions.  it functions until I attempt to get() the data out.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `S1=Entry(...).grid(...)`, what is stored in `S1` is the result of the grid function, which is always `None`. If you want to store a reference to the widget then you need to call grid separately.

Try this to see:

```
S1 = Entry(attr, width=3)
S1.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Comment: Ah.  all the difference in the world.  I've tried it, and it's still giving me the error that SEN is not defined when i try to use it after.

Comment: @DJ80: that sounds like a completely different problem. Ask another question -- comments aren't the place for an extended discussion.

Comment: @BryanOakley I always wondered why grid would not work as DJ80 expected out of the box. I use a modified version that returns a reference and it is much better.

Comment: @Phelix: my guess is because constructs like `Button(...).grid(...)` are extremely uncommon in the world of tcl/tk, and Tkinter is just a thin wrapper around tcl/tk. Personally I think it's better to decouple the creation of the widgets from their layout. I've found that often I'll change the layout of my widgets, and having all of that in one block of code makes refactoring _much_ easier.

Comment: @BryanOakley I'm a little skeptic but will sure give this advice a try - thanks.